# How can I pass oauth token or oauthaccesstokeid to javascript from Mule cloud connector

Tags: oauth, mule

I am using some Cloud Connectors in Mule that use OAuth and authorize the connector using the authorizre message processor. Afte rlogging in with the service provider I can get the access token for future invocations using the OauthAccessTokenId.

I am interacting with this via Javascript. I have a login button that runs the authorize flow in Mule. And then I have a seperate flow for invoking api methods. But how can I pass the oauthaccesstokenid back to the Javascript app in the auth flow so I can pass it back to Mule to invoke the API?

After the authorize processor I am doing a 302 redirect back to my javascript app and storing the oauthaccesstokenid in a cookie. Is this the best way? ANy thoughts on Security also?

Comment: Just to be sure: you're talking OAuth1 or OAuth2 here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*NOTE: Assuming you're talking about OAuth2.*

What you're describing is a typical scenario where the [OAuth2 Implicit Grant](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.2) would be useful: with this grant type, the access token is provided to the web browser (thus the JavaScript code it hosts) via a request fragment.

I'm not sure Cloud Connectors support this natively though. If not, going for a cookie would work too.

As far as security is concerned, the only problem I can see with a cookie as opposed to passing the token in a fragment, is that it will be persisted on the client. This said these tokens are usually short lived (worth checking what's the TTL of the token you receive) so the attack surface would not be wide.

Comment: Thanks David. I'm using the Salesforce cloud connector and I think it uses the Authorization code flow for server-server. At the moment I'm just using th oauthaccesstokenid flowVar to match users between requests. I guess I could make my authorization code flow mimic the implicit grant flow as a facade over the authorization flow and pass in a callback from javascript for the fragment. The current cookie solution seems to tightly couple my mule flow to the client side app. What are your thoughts on that approach?

Comment: The flow you're building is specific to the client side app anyways so I don't think the cookie dramatically increases coupling. Replacing the cookie with a fragment would have the advantage of familiarity with the implicit grant approach...

Comment: The only thing I'm worried about is the fact that SF may give you a more trusted token from the Authorization code flow and it may be a security issue to pass it back to the client app. You need to be sure it's fine to do so. Alternatively, you'd have to store the token in Mule, generate a session ID associated with this token and provide the session ID instead. That way the client would never have the token in hand.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any example etc. for handling sessions across JavaScript/Mule? Also, I am not passing back the access token itself but the OAuthAccessTokenId which is a reference to all the oauth info for that user in Mules object store. So this can only be used via my Mule flow. So maybe this id is safe enough to use as a session id? And just pass that back via a cookie or fragment.

Comment: I don't know of any such example. And yes, then, if this is just a symbolic ID, you're fine.